# nginx - gunicorn - django allauth redirect to 127.0.0.1 issue, how can I solve this?

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I want to deploy my django app with nginx-gunicorn.

so I set nginx and gunicorn conf like this.

```
/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf included by /etc/nginx/nginx.conf


server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my.domain.com; 
    charset utf-8;
    location /static/ {
        root /home/flood/dj-eruces-ango;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        #include proxy_params;
        #proxy_pass http://unix:/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket; 
        }

}
```

```
/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service

[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=flood
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/flood/dj-eruces-ango/
ExecStart=/home/flood/dj-eruces-ango/secure/bin/gunicorn \
        --workers 2 \
        --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 \
        config.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and I set my google social-auth api to 'my.domain.com' and 'my.domain.com/auth/google/login/callback/'

but when I try social auth, the error occurs below.

400 error: redirect_uri_mismatch
http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/google/login/callback/

I want to solve this.
show localhost issue(not a my.domain.com) and redirect_uri_mismatch issue.

How can I try?